# Changing the color of sections-subsections in the head II

Tags: beamer

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500742/changing-the-color-of-sections-subsections-in-the-head), we have

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}

%------------------------\AtBeginSubsection[]----------------------
\AtBeginSubsection[]{
\begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering,plain]{Outline}
\transsplitverticalout
\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}
}

\usetheme{Madrid}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=blue!30!black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=yellow!30!white,fg=blue!30!black}
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{bg=blue!30!black,fg=white}
%----------------------------------------------------------------

\title[The essential numerical range and the Olsen problem]{The
essential numerical range and the Olsen problem}
\author[{Student} (University of ....)]{Student}

\useoutertheme{shadow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\colorlet{titleleft}{blue!30!black}
\colorlet{titleright}{blue!30!black}

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}

\setbeamercolor*{subsection in head/foot}{bg=yellow!30!white,fg=blue!30!black}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]
{beamer@frametitleshade}
{\paperheight}{%
color(0pt)=(titleleft);
color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)}
\makeatother

%-----------------------------footline-----------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
%            \hspace*{3em}
%            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{page number in head/foot}%
%            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\vskip0pt%
}
%--------------------------------------------------
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!30!black}
\colorlet{myyellow}{yellow!30!white}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=myyellow,fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{bg=myblue,fg=white}

\setbeamercolor*{subsection in head/foot}{bg=myyellow,fg=myblue}

\colorlet{titleleft}{myblue}  %<----- left half of frame title background color
\colorlet{titleright}{myblue} %<----- right half of frame title background color
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white} %<---- Color of the frame title text
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Positive linear relations}
\section{Lattice linear relations}
\section{Domination by a positive compact relation.}
\subsection{Linear relation}
\subsection{Riesz spaces}
\begin{frame}{Linear relations}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> I want to change the color of the title frame to for example the `grey` instead of `blue` and the color of sections to `blue` instead of `black`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the background color of the section titles in the header from black to your blue, add `\setbeamercolor*{section in head/foot}{bg=myblue, fg=white}` and to change the background color of the frame title from your blue to gray, replace `\colorlet{titleleft}{myblue} \colorlet{titleright}{myblue}` by `\colorlet{titleleft}{gray} \colorlet{titleright}{gray}`.

As A Diyanat already explained in [their answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500776/134144), `bg` changed the background color and `fg` changed the font color.

[image]

---

As requested in teh comments, here is the complete MWE with some hopefully helpful explanatory annotations:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}

%------------------------\AtBeginSubsection[]----------------------
\AtBeginSubsection[]{
\begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering,plain]{Outline}
\transsplitverticalout
\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}
}


\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{shadow}

%-----------------custom frame title background--------------------
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]
{beamer@frametitleshade}
{\paperheight}{%
color(0pt)=(titleleft);
color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)}
\makeatother

%-----------------------------footline-----------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
%            \hspace*{3em}
%            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{page number in head/foot}%
%            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\vskip0pt%
}



%%%%% Custom color definitions used in the head and foot line of the frames %%%%%
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!30!black} %<----- define the new color myblue
\colorlet{myyellow}{yellow!30!white} %<----- define the new color myyellow

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=myblue} %<----- background color of author in footline
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=myyellow,fg=myblue} %<----- background color and font color for presentation title in footline 
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{bg=myblue,fg=white} %<----- background and font color fot page numbers in the footline

\setbeamercolor*{section in head/foot}{bg=myblue, fg=white} %<----- background and font color for the sections in the header
\setbeamercolor*{subsection in head/foot}{bg=myyellow,fg=myblue} %<----- background and font color for the subsections in the header

\colorlet{titleleft}{gray}  %<----- left half of frame title background color
\colorlet{titleright}{gray} %<----- right half of frame title background color
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white} %<---- Color of the frame title text
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%% Title and Author Information %%%%%
\title[The essential numerical range and the Olsen problem]{The
essential numerical range and the Olsen problem}
\author[{Student} (University of ....)]{Student}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Positive linear relations}
\section{Lattice linear relations}
\section{Domination by a positive compact relation.}
\subsection{Linear relation}
\subsection{Riesz spaces}
\begin{frame}{Linear relations}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. Please juste could you please write me the necessary codes  because I think that some codes can be ommited such that `\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=blue!30!black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=yellow!30!white,fg=blue!30!black}
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{bg=blue!30!black,fg=white}`

Comment: @Student: Sorry, but there seems to be a misunderstanding originating from the suggestion in [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500746/134144).  Either use `\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=blue!30!black}` OR `\colorlet{myblue}{blue!30!black}\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=myblue}` not both.

Comment: The latter is especially useful if you want to use the same blude color for more than one element and maybe later on decide that you would like to use a slightly different shade of blue. In this case, you will only have to change the definition of `\colorlet{myblue}{blue!30!black}` instead of touching every `\setbeamercolor...`.

Comment: If this is not what you refered to, please add some further explanation especially regarding "the necessary codes".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just I hope to include in this answer the code for my benifit and the benifit of the reader. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Student: I have edited my answer to included a complete MWE with some explanatory annotations in the code. I hope this helps you. If there are still some unanswered questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is great and clear.

Answer (score 2):

To change the foreground and background colors of the beamer frame, you could use the following lines:

```
\colorlet{titleleft}{gray!80}  %<----- left half of frame title background color
\colorlet{titleright}{gray!60} %<----- right half of frame title background color
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white} %<---- Color of the frame title text
```

Also for changing left frame header, we have:

```
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=Blue,fg=red}
```

It is worth noting that 'fg' and 'bg' means the foreground and background colors, respectively. In summary consider the following sample:

```
 \documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{shadow}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]
{beamer@frametitleshade}
{\paperheight}{%
 color(0pt)=(titleleft);
color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)}
\makeatother

\colorlet{titleleft}{gray!80}
\colorlet{titleright}{gray!60}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=Blue,fg=white}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Positive linear relations}
\begin{frame}{Linear relations}
Example.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]